# See if list of rows exists in a file

Tags: bash, grep

say I have a file with (it will have about 5 million rows - lets say they are present in a big.txt file)

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

and I want to check that the file contains rows with:

```
d
g
f
```

(35 items to query - let's say they belong in a query.txt file)

what is the best way to query that?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `d, g and f` one after the other in this specific order?

Comment: `grep -f` should work for you.

Comment: @fedorqui - I want to check that all the items exist - I don't care about the order

Comment: @anubhava - grep -f will query one pattern on a certain file - I have multiple patterns I want to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -f` to look for matches of one file in the other. And then, compare the output with the original file:

```
diff <(grep -f f2 f1 | sort) <(sort f2)
```

#### Test

With your given files:

```
$ diff <(grep -f f2 f1 | sort) <(sort f2)
$
```

Changing to

```
$ cat f2
z
g
f

$ diff <(grep -f f2 f1 | sort) <(sort f2)
2a3
> z
```

---

You can also use `cmp`:

```
cmp <(grep -f f2 f1 | sort) <(sort f2)
```

See with original files:

```
$ cat f2
d
g
f

$ if cmp <(grep -f f2 f1 | sort) <(sort f2) &>/dev/null; then echo "equal"; fi
equal
```

With different one:

```
$ cat f2
z
g
f

$ if cmp <(grep -f f2 f1 | sort) <(sort f2) &>/dev/null; then echo "equal"; fi
$
```

Comment: oh, its because you're diffing the files. interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} length(a) && $0 in a{delete a[$0]} 
     END {print (length(a))?"Does not exist":"Exists"}' f2 f1
```

- Here f2 is small file with 35 items
- f1 is bigger file with millions of items
- This awk reads all the lines of f2 file in memory (array)
- Then it checks array content against lines of f1 and deleting array element every time an item is matched
- Finally if array is empty then it means f2 is fully matched in f1 otherwise not.

Comment: give error `awk: line 1: illegal reference to array a`

Comment: Which version of awk you have as it worked for me on OSX and using gnu awk.

Comment: i use awk on linux ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score -1):

`pcregrep` is a freely-available replacemente of `grep` which fully supports Perl-compatible regular expressions: in particular, regular expressions with newline in them.  Hence, your problem could be solved as follows:

```
pcregrep -M "c\n(.*\n)*f(.*\n)*g" inputfile
```